# if then else statment returns "parse error on input `if'" in haskell

Tags: haskell, if-statement

I just can't get this to work. Keeps giving me the error "parse error on input `if'" in sublime.

```
trueChar char 
    if char == "True"
        then True 
        else False
```

Comment: Looks like your are missing an `=`. Replace the line `trueChar char` with `trueChar char =`.

Comment: Note that `char` in `char == ".."` is not actually a char, but a string. It's a misleading choice of a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing an equal sign, this is correct:

```
trueChar char =
    if char == "True"
        then True 
        else False
```

Comment: ...but don't write `if foo then True else False`. Just write `foo` instead.